# Div won't stay in place

Tags: css

Why does the red box move a bit to the left once the aqua box has been filled with so much content (by clicking 'fill') that down-scrolling is necessary? Thanks!

```
 /* For code, see jsfiddle */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeQSJ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XeQSJ/3/)**

**css**

```
html,body{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the scrollbar which appears which pushes everything to the left!! :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't see this. How embarrasing.

Answer (score 0):

The browser you are using probably doesn't display a scroll bar if its not required.

Therefore when it is required, your window width size will decrease, and potentially move elements.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar doesn't appear until it is needed, you can keep things constant by always displaying a scrollbar, in your css:

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```